# 2d pool collision with rotational motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, collision, rotation

I'm trying to calculate a collision between two 2d disks with rotational motion.
The collision is perfectly elastic: the sum of translational and rotational energy is conserved. In the instant of the collision the contact of disks' surface is without slipping. Could you give me hint for this calculation?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself, since if we do not know where you got stuck we also do not know what kinds of hints to give.

Comment: I wrote the energy, momenta, angular momentum conservation equations, but this isn't enough. I tried some different equations for the tangent speeds in the point of contact, these weren't fit in the equation system. So I need some hint for the missing equation.

Comment: My first thought is that you may not have written separate equations for x and y components of momentum. If that isn't it, maybe you could show us the equations you wrote?

Comment: y: components parallel with surface tangent in collision point.

px1 + px2 = px1' + px2'  |  

py1 + py2 = py1' + py2'  |  

L1 + L2 = L1' + L2'   |  

(px1^2 + px2^2 + py1^2 + py2^2)/2m + (L1^2 + L2^2)/2Q = same with ' members   |   

And one in the collision point (no slipping):

p1y'/m + L1'/Q*R = p2y'/m - L2'/Q*R

One additional equation is needed, but I couldn't figure out what is it.

Comment: instead of writing the energy equation you could write the 2 equations for coefficient of restitution (= one for elastic)

Comment: See answer on linked duplicate question.

Comment: Or [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244317/392) answer

Answer (score 0):

If you impose a non slip condition, then you say that during the collision both disks have the same tangential speed. You can calculate this speed (both the translational speed and the rotational speed contribute) and impose a final common tangential speed, plus the conservation of the angular momentum. The problem with this is that now you have an additional constraint (and most likely find that there are no solutions). I did not run the numbers for a collision of this kind, but I highly suspect that it is not consistent with an elastic collision.